# changing int band values to names

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have the contents of an xarray.DataArray, geotiffs_da, formed by reading data from several geoTIFF files. Some of the xarray content is as follows:

geotiffs_da_renamed
<xarray.DataArray (time: 10, band: 9, latitude: 101, longitude: 101)>
array([[[[1065., 1041., 1036., ..., 1069., 1025., 1028.],
...
[4342., 4192., 4022., ..., 3468., 3458., 3469.]]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:

- band       (band) int32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- latitude   (latitude) float64 13.8 13.8 13.8 13.8 ... 13.79 13.79 13.79
- longitude  (longitude) float64 -15.79 -15.79 -15.79 ... -15.78 -15.78 -15.78
- time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-07-18 2021-07-23 ... 2021-11-20

The original xarray had 'x' and 'y' in place of longitude and latitude, and I was able to change these using

geotiffs_da = geotiffs_da.rename ( { 'x': 'longitude', 'y': 'latitude' } )

How do I change the contents of 'band' so that it shows blue, green, red, ..., rather than 1, 2, 3, ...?

Answer (score 0):

`assign_coords()` will do this. Documentation is [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign_coords.html)

Here is an example:

```py
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

#============================
# create sample dataset (ds)
#============================
# create dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                   'y':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]}).set_index('x')

# convert to dataset
ds = df.to_xarray()

#============================
# assign new x coordinate
# to list of colors
#============================
ds = ds.assign_coords(x=['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet'])
```

`ds.assign_coords(x=...)` assigns the coordinate x to the list of colors. Since Xarray always returns an object and doesn't have an `inplace=True` option like Pandas, we have to either replace the original dataset (ds) or assign it to something else.